# How to deal with list of partial API data in ember

Tags: ember.js

(Ember 2, if it matters)

I am trying to show a list of search results on an ember page. The api I am using basically just returns a list of ids and names for a particular record type (let's call it foo). Unfortunately, I also need to get a thumbnail with each item and the search results route doesn't provide it. The search-result model is comprised of a list of several attributes, each of which is simply a `DS.hasMany` to a different model, e.g.

```
  foos: DS.hasMany('foo', {
    async: true
  }),
  bars: DS.hasMany('bar', {
    async: true
  }),
```

The data returned from the server looks like this:

```
{
    "actions": [{
        ... irrelevant
    }],
    "data": {
        "foos": [{
            "id": "test",
            "name": "test"
        }],
        "meta": {
            "total": 1
        }
    }
}
```

Foo's model has lots of properties, including `name`, `thumbnailURI`, etc.

When I try to use `{{foo.image}}` in my template, the property is undefined; I would have expected the store to fetch the model for `foo/test`, since it's missing the image property, but it doesn't. What am I supposed to do to tell Ember -- hey, that list of items from the server didn't get all of the properties you need; go ask the server for that data for each item via `/api/foo/test`, `/api/foo/test2`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ember-data` is not good with partitial loaded models. Best way to go is to split your model into two parts. One `normal` model and one `detail` model.

Then you can work around this in your adapter/serializer.
Generally its not clear what adapter/pair you are using, but lets assume you have the models `foo` and `foo-detail`:

**foo**

```
name: DS.attr('string'),
detail: DS.belongsTo('foo-detail'),
bars: DS.hasMany('bar'),
```

**foo-detail**

```
image: DS.attr('string'),
```

Then your serializer for `foo` would have to return something like this:

```
{
    data: [{
        id: 'test',
        type: 'foo',
        attributes: {
            name: 'first foo'
        },
        relationships: {
            "foo-detail": {
                links: {
                    related: '/foo/test'
                }
            }
        }
    },{...}]
}
```

This will enforce a request to `/foo/test` when you access `{{fooInstance.detail.image}}`. Next you have to make sure that the serializer for `foo-detail` will return this:

```
{
    data: {
        id: 'test',
        type: 'foo-detail',
        attributes: {
            image: '/testimage.jpg'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Mind just elaborating a bit on your last sentence? I'm new to ember still; I know what those are but am not immediately sure what the general steps you are think of would be.

Comment: Thank you, this should help me and hopefully others.